# Skipping every other value in nested tuple

Tags: python

I am trying to skip over every other list in my nested list.

```
filled_list = [1,2,3,[11,2,3,[111,2,3,[1111,2,3,4]]]]

def iterative_list(value):
    while isinstance(value[-1], list):
        a, *_, value = value
        yield a
    yield value[0]

z = iterative_list(filled_list)
```

How can I do that so the output goes from

`[1, 11, 111, 1111]` Parsing a list iteratively.

to

`[1, 111,]` Parsing a list iteratively.

I know the concept that you can skip over every other element from a list with [::2] notation, but how can I apply this to a nested list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append all `a`s to a list, then `return` the list, like:

```
def iterative_list(value):
   l=[]
   while isinstance(value[-1], list):
       a, *_, value = value
       l.append(a)
   l.append(a)
   return l[::2]
```

And now:

```
print(iterative_list(filled_list))
```

Is:

```
[1, 111]
```

Comment: oh. I feel so stupid now, but thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @EvanKim Happy to help always, :-), , can accept later if you want :-)

Comment: I actually had to wait a minute before I could accept the answer haha, done now!

Comment: @EvanKim Yup because it was too early then, haha.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `try-except` block in an infinite loop to keep getting the inner-inner list until it catches a `TypeError` or `IndexError`:

```
def iterative_list(value):
    while True:
        try:
            yield value[0]
            value = value[-1][-1]
        except (TypeError, IndexError):
            break
```

so that `list(iterative_list(filled_list))` returns:

```
[1, 111]
```

Comment: Interesting. I will have to test which one is faster!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more efficient solution, as it's [easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html).

Answer (score 1):

Generator with recursion:

```
def iterative_list(value):
    try:
        yield value[0]
        yield from iterative_list(value[-1][-1])
    except TypeError:
        return
```

Example:

```
list(iterative_list(filled_list))
Out: [1, 111]
```